# How can I get Windows file explorer to behave the way I want?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, windows-desktop-search

I have a set of behaviors I would like to have Windows 11 File Explorer to have, very different from the behaviors it now has. I would like to know if there is a way to make it do some or all of these things.

1. When I open a new file explorer or My Computer window, I want it to start at the top of the entire directory tree, including the sub-trees on both my SSD and my regular hard drive.  At the top of that view and every other view, I want it to show the top-level folder I am in, and all the folders that exist within that folder, and the subfolders of each, and their sub-folders, etc., in a tree-like structure.
2. Underneath this folder tree, I want to see all the files that exist in any of the folders displayed as above, and no files that exist under any directory that is not a sub-directory of the topmost current directory..
3. When in the detailed view, after clicking on a column heading, I want all the files that exist under the top-level folder, directly or indirectly,  sorted on the column selected (e.g. name, date, type) and ONLY on that column, with no sub-categories having sort priority above the column sort. Within and only within items sorted to the same place by the column sort, I would like files sorted by the “Group by” variable if there is one. Currently this order is reversed, i.e. column sort takes place only within the  “group by” source.

It would not have occurred to me that when sorting files on, e.g., date, that files would actually be sorted on date only within file types, but that is how my file explorer behaves. I do not think type is exactly the same as extension, but I believe that extensions are not divided between types.

Comment: Windows explorer is not very modabble. But you can make your own file explorer replacement (which programming languages do you know?) or use one of the many existing options like xplorer2.